# VBA web scrape innertext

Tags: excel, vba, web

I have now tried for quite some time to web scrape this innertext:
I want the value 0606 copied to an Excel sheet

```
<TABLE class="group"
<td width="100%" nowrap="" colspan="3">
<input name="pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityQualifier" 
type="HIDDEN" value="CPR">CPR-nr:
<input name="pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue" 
type="HIDDEN" value="0606">0606</td>
```

I have tried through get.attribute,getelementbyclassname, value and innertext, but now I need some fresh eyes on it. 
Does any of you have a good idea?

Comment: So, that's the web source code.  If you need fresh eyes on your code, wouldn't it be a good idea to post your code?

Comment: Did you try the answers given?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, however without your code I don't know how you're obtaining your `HTMLDocument`:

```
Dim oHTMLDocument As Object
Dim ele As Object

Set oHTMLDocument = ... 'No code provided so I'm unsure how you obtained the HTMLDocument

For Each ele in oHTMLDocument.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If ele.Name = "pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue" Then
        Debug.Print ele.innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next ele
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS selector and avoid the need for a loop.

```
input[name="pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue"]
```

[image: CSS query]

[Try it](http://try.jsoup.org/~m26N_s6sCXCZ0x7O0vJ0I2N9EdU)

---

VBA

`.querySelector` is accessed via the HTML document set when you have your page (method not shown in your question) but with Internet Explorer for example:

```
IE.document.querySelector("pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue").innerText
```

---

Further info:

[HTML DOM querySelector() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)